# Robot SSHLibrary pass ssh connection to my library class

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

Using SSHLibrary currently I execute ssh commands in test suite file or keyword file. Is it possible to do that in my current library file? Meaning my library function just forms the string now. I wanted to executed that in ssh connection in library file.

test/testsuit.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library         SSHLibrary
Library         ${EXEC_DIR}/lib/mylib.py  WITH NAME  llib
Suite Setup     open_connection_and_login
Suite Teardown  Close All Connections

*** Variables ***
${HOST}      10.x.x.x.x
${USERNAME}  myuser
${PASSWORD}  mypassword

*** Test Cases ***
example test
    ${sshstring}= llib.form_the_sshstring   ls
    ${output}=  Execute Command     {sshstring}

*** Keywords ***
open_connection_and_login
    Open Connection  ${HOST}
    Login  ${USERNAME}  ${PASSWORD}
```

lib/mylib.py

```
def form_the_sshstring(input):
    sshstring = "{}".format(ls)
    return sshstring
```

Expecting something like..

```
*** Test Cases ***
example test
    ${output}= llib.run_the_sshstring   ls
```

/lib/mylib.py

```
import SSHLibrary
    def run_the_sshstring(input):
        sshstring = "{}".format(ls)
        out = SSHLibrary.SSHCleint(sshstring)
        return out
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question. What would be the difference? What are you trying to achive? Does your provided code not work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within your library file you can get a reference to the imported SSHLibrary -- and thus, it's keywords -- with the built-in keyword [Get Library Instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance). With that, you can call the SSHLibrary keyword [Execute Command](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Execute%20Command)

### Example:

```
# mylib.py
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def run_the_sshstring(input):
    sshlib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SSHLibrary")
    result = sshlib.execute_command(input)
    return result
```

Comment: you are savior Thanks!

Comment: one more question, is possible to get active sshClient or pass the client to my custom library.py? Because if I use get_library_instance it causes trouble libdoc.

Comment: @WoodChopper: Probably. I haven't tried it. You can call `get_library_instance` from your test, and pass the result to your keyword.